# set focus() on textbox on form onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set focus on a textbox in a form that's a part of jQuery tree. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       $("#search").focus();

});
```

HTML:

```
 <div>
     <form action="search" method="post" name="frmSearch>
          <label for="search">Search:</label>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div>
```

When I click on Search tab in the tree, it won't set focus on the textbox. Can someone let me know what's wrong in the code?

Comment: close the parenthesis

Comment: As soon as you click the page, the focus will be removed from the input and given to whatever you just clicked

Comment: What do you mean by "click on the Search tab"?

Comment: I mistyped in here, but I have the closing semi-colon in my actual code

Comment: If you made a typo in your post, click the edit link at the bottom of your question and correct the mistake. Leaving the typo in the question will make it difficult for you to get a correct answer.

Comment: its a jQuery collapsible tree structure with different tabs..one of them is search. If I click on the Search tab, I want the focus to set on search text box

Comment: Just make sure you don't have more than one element sharing the same ID (search).

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu The user should only mark an answer as accepted if it meets their needs. It's considered bad form here to ask people to accept your answer if they haven't indicated it answered their question.

Comment: cfs: he has forgotten it and went away anyway.

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu .. your answer is gone again.

Answer (score 6):

You're focusing the textbox on page load, however as soon as you click anywhere else on the page (such as a tab), the focus will be removed from the textbox and given to whatever you just clicked.

Instead of focusing on page load, attach a click listener to your tab so that when it is clicked the `search` textbox gets focus. Since I haven't seen all your markup, I'm using `#mySearchTab` as a placeholder for the ID of your search tab:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mySearchTab").on('click', function() {
       $('#search').focus();
    });
});
```

Also, don't forget to close your functions with a `)`.

I'm not sure what your tree looks like but here's a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fXLn/) using jQuery tabs.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this - please explain. This is the only answer that seems to address the issue in the OP

Comment: yep, some valid points against this option too. somehow I still can't agree though ;) but lets leave this at that because this is probably not the area for that discussion (I normally consider anybody who down-votes on a good post without any comment as a troll :P)

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu, I don't see your answer.. sorry, I am new here, am I missing something

Comment: @user2675939 I updated with demo using jQuery tabs to show how this answer would work. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I made some modification in your js codes

**http://jsfiddle.net/8CTqN/5**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $("#search2").focus();      
    });
});
```

Comment: why are you doing this?

Comment: to show him working example of his codes for better visualization

Comment: but you remove the call to focus on load, you don't attempt to give focus. this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: "When I click on Search tab in the tree, it won't set focus on the textbox." Seems he wants the textbox to gain focus when he clicks the search tab.

Comment: The problem is not that the input is not gaining focus on document load, and even if it was, wrapping the `focus()` call in an anonymous function wouldn't help. The problem is that the input is not gaining focus when a tab is clicked to display content that contains that input.

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu This still isn't addressing the issue. `$(document).ready(function(){` and `$(function(){` are equivalent, so you are just attaching two listeners to the document.ready event. It might help you to slow down a bit and read the question closely to get a thorough understanding of it. Then think through your answer and test it before posting. This approach has been helpful for me, I hope it serves you.

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```
$(function(){
    $("input:first:text").focus();       
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8CTqN/2/

tested on chrome

Comment: What's different here? The problem is not with the selector.

Comment: Might not work as wanted when there are multiple text input elements. Don't take this as a negative comment, I am just highlighting this point.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: i dont know why my firefox not focusing when first. chrome does that.

Comment: @Harry: thanks for correcting me... now it will focus very first input.

Comment: The problem is not that it isn't gaining focus on document ready, but that it isn't gaining focus when the user clicks on a tab that the content is contained within.